# Is rich:fileUpload component in (RC 4.3.4) working on Apache Tomcat7 and JSF 2.2 ? : "Request prolog cannot be read"

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces, tomcat7, view-scope

I'm trying to upload a file with richfaces fileupload component. My bean is in a viewscoped.

My code extracted from the showcase.

```
            <rich:fileUpload  id="upload" immediateUpload="true" fileUploadListener="#{analyse.listener}"  acceptedTypes="png" ontyperejected="alert('Seulement les fichiers avec l'extension bam et pdf sont acceptés.');" maxFilesQuantity="3">
                  <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" />        
            </rich:fileUpload>
```

The bean function called :

```
    public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {


    System.out.println("Listenner");

    UploadedFile item = event.getUploadedFile();

    System.out.println(item.getName());
    System.out.println(item.getSize());
    System.out.println(item.getContentType()) ;

}
```

And i get a beautiful error when i try to add a file for upload :-( . Help is welcome.

> 6 nov. 2013 19:00:43 org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25
>   parseIfNecessary GRAVE: Exception parsing multipart request: Request
>   prolog cannot be read org.richfaces.exception.FileUploadException:
>   Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read    at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:156)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.parseIfNecessary(MultipartRequest25.java:77)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.getParameter(MultipartRequest25.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:56)
>     at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.get(Collections.java:1280)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.UIDebug.debugRequest(UIDebug.java:168)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash$PreviousNextFlashInfoManager.decode(ELFlash.java:1268)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getCurrentFlashManager(ELFlash.java:1093)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.doPrePhaseActions(ELFlash.java:569)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:215)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Request prolog cannot be read    at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.readProlog(MultipartRequestParser.java:270)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.initialize(MultipartRequestParser.java:172)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:148)
>     ... 70 more 6 nov. 2013 19:00:43
>   com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash$PreviousNextFlashInfoManager
>   decode GRAVE: JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming
>   cookie value 3Xfn_.  Processing will continue, but the flash is
>   unavailable for this request. 6 nov. 2013 19:00:43
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke GRAVE:
>   "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet facesServlet a lancé une exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:485)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:73)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:619)
>     at
>   javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.context.PartialResponseWriterWrapper.startDocument(PartialResponseWriterWrapper.java:32)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) 6 nov. 2013 19:00:43
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke GRAVE:
>   "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet facesServlet a généré une
>   exception java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:485)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:73)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:619)
>     at
>   javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.context.PartialResponseWriterWrapper.startDocument(PartialResponseWriterWrapper.java:32)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) 6 nov. 2013 19:00:43
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25 parseIfNecessary GRAVE:
>   Exception parsing multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read
>   org.richfaces.exception.FileUploadException: Exception parsing
>   multipart request: Request prolog cannot be read  at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:156)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.parseIfNecessary(MultipartRequest25.java:77)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequest25.getParameter(MultipartRequest25.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:75)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.RequestParameterMap.get(RequestParameterMap.java:56)
>     at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.get(Collections.java:1280)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.UIDebug.debugRequest(UIDebug.java:168)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash$PreviousNextFlashInfoManager.decode(ELFlash.java:1268)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getCurrentFlashManager(ELFlash.java:1093)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.doPrePhaseActions(ELFlash.java:569)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:215)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:428)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Request prolog cannot be read    at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.readProlog(MultipartRequestParser.java:270)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.initialize(MultipartRequestParser.java:172)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.request.MultipartRequestParser.parse(MultipartRequestParser.java:148)
>     ... 34 more 6 nov. 2013 19:00:43
>   com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash$PreviousNextFlashInfoManager
>   decode GRAVE: JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming
>   cookie value 3Xfn_.  Processing will continue, but the flash is
>   unavailable for this request. 6 nov. 2013 19:00:43
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke GRAVE:
>   "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet facesServlet a lancé une exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:485)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:73)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:619)
>     at
>   javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.richfaces.context.PartialResponseWriterWrapper.startDocument(PartialResponseWriterWrapper.java:32)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:199)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Summary:** Use `<h:inputFile />`, at least I couldn't get `<rich:fileUpload>` to work in JSF-2.2

**Long version:**
After spending a day messing around with `<rich:fileUpload>` I came to the conclusion that servlet containers adhering to the Servlet-3.0 spec are left between a rock and a hard place here.

What seems to be happening is that Tomcat (or any servlet container implementing Servlet-3.0 and above - I tried with Wildfly's undertow) makes multipart POST submits available via the [HttpServletRequest#getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) method. It also parses the form data nicely and makes it available via [ServletRequest#getParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29), which explicitly states:

> If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via getInputStream() or getReader() can interfere with the execution of this method.

Which is exactly what `MultipartRequest25` does if you call it's `getParameter` method with a non-existing parameter name:

```
 String parameter = super.getParameter(name);
 if (parameter != null) {
     return parameter;
 }
 parseIfNecessary();
```

The `parseIfNecessary()` part tries to read the prolog, but since the container already has parsed the request body the stream is empty and reading from it produces an immediate `EOF` which is translated to the `IOException` we're seeing.

From the class naming I get the idea that this was written for Servlet-2.5 containers where this probably worked and the info wasn't readily available.

At this point, I decided to leverage my use of JSF-2.2 and switch to [h:inputFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/h/inputFile.html) which works splendid when you use the latest (at this time of writing) Mojarra-2.2.5 (haven't tried Myfaces).

Here's an example:

```
<h:form id="fileUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile value="#{docMgr.file}" required="true">
        <f:ajax listener="#{docMgr.saveFile}" render="@form" />
    </h:inputFile>
    <h:messages />
</h:form>
```

Note that versions before Mojarra-2.2.5 had issues with ajax submits like in the example above (which mimicks RichFaces' `immediateUpload`.

Comment: For the records, there is an issue-tracker entry for it: [RF-13444](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-13444). The issue seems solved for RichFaces 5 but at least RichFaces 4.3.5 still suffers from this bug.

Comment: The same problme on JBOSS 8

Comment: @mabi I am currently using Mojarra 2.2.6 and RichFaces 4.3.4 and my listener doesn't get called (but the Part is updated), were you having this issue?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie no, I was experiencing the error posted in the question. So, dunno, new problem?

Comment: @mabi Well tested with Mojarra 2.2.5 and RichFaces 4.3.4, same issue, I think I'll post a question! Without RichFaces, it works!

Comment: @mabi Thank you for the great explanation of the problem!