# Richfaces 3 on Payara 5: Request prolog cannot be read

Tags: jsf, glassfish, richfaces, jsf-1.2, payara

I'm attempting to move an existing **Richfaces** 3.3.4 / **JSF** 1.2 application off Glassfish 3 (for a number of reasons) onto Payara 5.192.  The application runs fine with a couple exceptions, the primary problem being `rich:fileUpload` doesn't work.

I added `multipart-config` to `web.xml`, but that didn't resolve the problem:

```xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>33554432</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>335544320</max-request-size>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
```

Here is the error:

```
org.ajax4jsf.exception.FileUploadException: IO Error parsing multipart request
    at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.parseRequest(MultipartRequest.java:388)
    at org.richfaces.component.FileUploadPhaselistener.beforePhase(FileUploadPhaselistener.java:63)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:74)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:367)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:385)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:373)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Request prolog cannot be read
    at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.readProlog(MultipartRequest.java:333)
    at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.initialize(MultipartRequest.java:369)
    at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.parseRequest(MultipartRequest.java:379)
    ... 47 more¡ëôwÍ$
```

Comment: If 'security' is one of the reasons to migrate you should migrate jsf 1.2 too (effectively even more important)

Comment: You need to add multipart support in form, which contains `fileUpload` component: `<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"> ... fileUpload ... </h:form>`, and you don't need multipart-config in web.xml.

Comment: @VasilLukach That was already present, and working when deployed to GF3.

Comment: "prolog cannot be read" usually means the server is passing data in a format RichFaces can't recognize. RF3 relies on Servlet 2.x, Payara probably uses 3.0 or higher.

Comment: GF3.1.2.2 used Servlet 3.0.  Payara 5 uses Servlet 4.  I didn't see anything in the 4.0 spec that would prevent a 2.x servlet from running in that container.

Comment: (I don't see your reply if you don't @ me). It's not an issue of spec as much as it an issue of implementation. The request is encoded differently (because you're expected to use the new API). Handling of requests from Servlet 3.0+ was added in 4.5. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19819377/1818198